# PrimeNG PanelMenu routerLink issue

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG (1.0.0-beta.5) PanelMenu with Angular RC 2.0.0-rc.1 version

Below is the sample code of PrimeNG panel menu. When I click on `Project` or `Welcome` links, it refreshes my entire page and then loads the corresponding component.

```
<p-panelMenu id="panelMenu">
    <div>
        <div><a data-icon="fa-file-o"><span>Report</span></a></div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a data-icon="fa-plus"><span>New</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Project']" (click)="mobileMenuActive = false">Project</a></li>
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Welcome']" (click)="mobileMenuActive = false">Welcome</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['Project']">Project</a></li>
                <li><a><span>Quit</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</p-panelMenu>
```

Whenever I use nav element like below, it properly calls respective component without page refresh.

```
<nav>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Welcome']">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Project']">Product List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Any idea what I am missing in primeNG panel-menu implementation?

Cheers
Sanket

Comment: Please try with beta7, the new menuitem api has dedicated routerLink property for this.

Answer (score 5):

You have several ways of using it.

The FIRST you set the panel menu:

```
//HTML
<p-panelMenu [model]="items"></p-panelMenu>
```

Then in your `.ts` file:

```
items: MenuItem[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Users',
            url:"/users" //<<<-------- This will reload the page and go /users
        },
        {
            label: 'Profile',
            routerLink:"/profile" //<<<-------- This works the same way as <a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a>
        },
        {
            label: 'Command',
            command:(click)=>{this.router.navigate(['/command']);} //<<<-------- Will not reload the page
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are some explanation of how it works:

- **url** => This is used for external navigation(external links), reason why it reloads the page when used;
- **routerLink** => It behaves like angular [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)
- **command** => it is used to invoke functions when the item is clicked. You can read more about [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menumodel)

Answer (score 3):

I am using primeng beta.6 version and still have this issue. The whole page refreshes when I navigate from the menu (not just the router-outlet area).

HTML:

```
<p-tabMenu class="ui-tabmenu" [model]="items"></p-tabMenu>
```

TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [    
           { label: 'Notes', icon: 'fa-file-o', url: ['Page1'] },
            { label: 'Companies', icon: 'fa-edit', url: ['Page2'] },
            { label: 'Google', icon: 'fa-plus', url: 'http://www.google.com' }
        ];
    }
```

I only want to refresh the view area and not refresh the menu. Is this still a problem in beta.6?

Comment: As for now, have found a workaround for this issue. Instead of using url, have to use command to write a angular router.navigate function:

{ label: 'Notes', icon: 'fa-file-o', command: (click) => {this.router.navigate(['Notes']);} },

Comment: Beta7 provides a dedicated routerLink attribute for the menuitem api such as routerLink: url: ['Page1']

Answer (score 1):

Refer this thread on prime community
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=45504

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at the solution provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000508/9943363. It worked for me.

Solution: Make sure to use the RouterLink as an array with a string representing file path as - routerLink:['\test\']

Comment: It is OK for an answer to contain links for reference but since links tend to go stale over time, the answer itself should at least contain a basic description of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[multiple]="false" helps

`<p-panelMenu [model]="menuItems" [multiple]="false"></p-panelMenu>`

Comment: Pleae explain your answer and add additional information to it. The answer, as it is right now, it not a suitable answer.